# Connect to MSSQL from PHP 5.4.3 with WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I am not able to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 from PHP 5.4.3 with the WampServer 2.2 (Windows).

I've already tried tons of different suggestions with no success.

I've enabled these PHP extensions:

- php_sqlsrv_54_ts
- php_sqlsrv_54_nts
- php_mssql
- php_pdo_mssql

**Errors:**

If I try to connect with `mssql_connect(...)`:

> Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

If I try to connect with new `PDO('sqlsrv:server=...)`:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

**phpinfo()**

There is nothing about sqlsrv_54_ts, sqlsrv_54_nts, mssql, pdo_mssql extensions, so these probably were not loaded.

> **Configure Command:** cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--without-dblib" "--without-pdo-dblib" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_11_2\sdk,shared" "--disable-debug-pack" "--disable-static-analyze"

Comment: What errors do you get? with `mysql_connect()` function ?

Comment: please tell what error you are getting ??

Comment: Are you sure the extensions are enabled and working? Check `phpinfo()` to be sure. If you want to use php_sqlsrv, you should be using [`sqlsrv_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Comment: mysql_connect() works properly, but I want to work with mssql_connect() or another MSSQL functions

Comment: @MilošHavlíček was your problem solved

Comment: unfortunatelly no that wasn't

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797951/php-on-iis7-with-pdo-ms-sql-support