# The sqlsrv PHP extension is not loaded properly or available for PHP to use

Tags: php, sql

I am attempting to migrate an old Wordpress 3.7 blog to a new web server running PHP 5.6.20 on a fully-patched version of Windows Server 2012 R2.

When I go to */wp-admin/* I get the following error:

> Extension Not Loaded 
>   The sqlsrv PHP extension is not loaded properly or available for PHP to use.
>
> Check your phpinfo Make sure it is loaded in your php ini file Turn on
>   display_errors and display_startup_errors so you can detect issues
>   with loading the module.

When I look at *phpinfo()*, I see:

```
sqlsrv

sqlsrv                          support         enabled
Directive                       Local Value     Master Value
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize    10240           10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity              0           0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems            0           0
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors   On          On
```

When I look in PHP Manager for IIS it shows *php_sqlsrv.dll* as **Enabled**

I do note on phpinfo() the following value for *Configure Command*:

cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" **"--without-mssql"** "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo

I am not sure if that has anything to do with it or how I change that value?

Comment: The important part is `--without-pdo-mssql` - you need to recompile your PHP. Also.. why run PHP on a windows server? You can't even use `php-fpm`, you'll be constrained to performance of your web server. If you have a choice, run it on *nix (I know that changing infrastructure is not always possible, so I'm making a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that I needed to install the 5.6 drivers found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc296172.aspx

This is the post that directed me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800615/3389346